# ObservableCollection Databinding performance

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections, observablecollection

I would like to know why according to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx) and observable collection binds significantly faster(20 ms vs 1685ms, that's 800X faster) than a List<> collection in WPF. I looked at the internals of ObservableCollection and it uses a List as it's storage collection object(I used reflector and saw this in the constructor)

```
public Collection()
{
    this.items = new List<T>();
}
```

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comparison in that article isn't between two simple binding operations, those measurements refer to a scenario in which you add a single item to a WPF `ListBox` that is already bound to either a `List<T>` or an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

As the author remarks:

> ...the CLR `List<T>` object 
>   does not automatically raise a
>   collection changed event. In order to
>   get the `ListBox` to pick up the
>   changes, you would have to recreate
>   your list of employees and re-attach
>   it to the `ItemsSource` property of the
>   `ListBox`. While this solution works, it
>   introduces a huge performance impact.
>   Each time you reassign the `ItemsSource`
>   of `ListBox` to a new object, the
>   `ListBox` first throws away its previous
>   items and regenerates its entire list.

This explains the performance difference. Even though `ObservableCollection<T>` is backed by a `List<T>`, it implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, which renders all that extra processing unnecessary.

Comment: More precisely INotifyCollectionChanged is implemented by ObservableCollection<T>

Comment: So, if we have a List<T> of 1000 items and an ObservableCollection<T> of 1000 items they would take the same amount of time, right? It makes sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that is correct - everything else being equal (<T> being the same type, nothing crazy happening when accessing the bound property, etc.), they would take the same amount of time.