# How to Avoid Firing ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged Multiple Times When Replacing All Elements Or Adding a Collection of Elements

Tags: c#, silverlight, observablecollection

I have `ObservableCollection<T>` collection, and I want to replace all elements with a new collection of elements, I could do:

```
collection.Clear();
```

OR:

```
collection.ClearItems();
```

(BTW, what's the difference between these two methods?)

I could also use `foreach` to `collection.Add` one by one, but this will fire multiple times

Same when adding a collection of elements.

EDIT:

I found a good library here: [Enhanced ObservableCollection with ability to delay or disable notifications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249311/Enhanced-ObservableCollection) but it seems that it does NOT support silverlight.

Comment: if you want to replace all items in first collection using other collection, can't just directly assign the new one to an old one?

Comment: If you do so, the collection itself will be changed, in which case you will lose the reference to the collection, i.e., your CollectionChanged event is gone.

Comment: reassign that event handler?

Comment: Reassign that event handler?  then what's the purpose of `CollectionChanged`? :-)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

ColinE is right with all his informations. I only want to add my subclass of `ObservableCollection` that I use for this specific case.

```
public class SmartCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> {
    public SmartCollection()
        : base() {
    }

    public SmartCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection) {
    }

    public SmartCollection(List<T> list)
        : base(list) {
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range) {
        foreach (var item in range) {
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void Reset(IEnumerable<T> range) {
        this.Items.Clear();

        AddRange(range);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for remembering to raise PropertyChanged for Count and Items[] - I'll have to update the code I use in my own projects ;-)

Comment: @Jehof: is it OK to just cut and paste your code into a project.  Or is it for reference only?  I'm asking for permission here.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala its free to use. Enjoy it. See also [this](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Comment: Why exactly do you need to raise separately for Count and Items[]? Does the observer not check this on reset?

Comment: @Aaron you need to raise the property changes on `Count` and `Item[]` also. Some observers may check these properties. Take a look at the implementation of ObservableCollection and you will see that all methods that manipulate the collection will raise the event for these properties.

Comment: @Jehof Why use Reset instead of Add?

Comment: @Mark13426 `this.Items.Xxxx()` is not firing notifications and this property is only can access from `SmartCollection` (or your subclasses of `ObservableCollection`). You got 2 times notifications if you use manually called `Clear()` and `Add`.

Comment: DynamicData provides an ObservableCollectionExtended which can suspend change notifications.

Comment: Excellent! The performance boost of this is staggering. I'm only displaying 1000 entries on a log page. This solution reduces the page navigation time from about 5 seconds to under 1.

Comment: I love this! I was wondering if anyone can expand on why `.Add` isn't being used. I tried it, and it appears the event is not firing at all, but when `.Reset` is used, the event fires. Any reason why that would be the case? I'm not clear on @hidekuro's response.

Comment: Can this simply be interchanged in place with ObservableCollection? I don't know if I can use AddRange or not so don't know how much difference it would make @Jehof

Comment: @bobsyauncle yes SmartCollection is a subclass of ObservableCollection. It only provides the additional methods AddRange and Reset

Comment: Ok. Looking for an ObservableCollection class that has some form of improvements to how the current one is done. I guess this one doesn't quite do that, but at least if we wanted to add a bunch we could

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this by subclassing `ObservableCollection` and implementing your own `ReplaceAll` method. The implementation of this methods would replace all the items within the internal `Items` property, then fire a `CollectionChanged` event. Likewise, you can add an `AddRange` method. For an implementation of this, see the answer to this question:

[ObservableCollection Doesn't support AddRange method, so I get notified for each item added, besides what about INotifyCollectionChanging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each)

The difference between `Collection.Clear` and `Collection.ClearItems` is that `Clear` is a public API method, whereas `ClearItems` is protected, it is an extension point that allows your to extend / modify the behaviour of `Clear`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I implemented for other folks' reference:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302933/how-to-avoid-firing-observablecollection-collectionchanged-multiple-times-when-r
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each
public class ObservableCollectionFast<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableCollectionFast()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollectionFast(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollectionFast(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {

    }

    public virtual void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return;

        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        // Cannot use NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, because Constructor supports only the 'Reset' action.
    }

    public virtual void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return;

        bool removed = false;
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            if (this.Items.Remove(item))
                removed = true;
        }

        if (removed)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            // Cannot use NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, because Constructor supports only the 'Reset' action.
        }
    }

    public virtual void Reset(T item)
    {
        this.Reset(new List<T>() { item });
    }

    public virtual void Reset(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection.IsNullOrEmpty() && this.Items.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return;

        // Step 0: Check if collection is exactly same as this.Items
        if (IEnumerableUtils.Equals<T>(collection, this.Items))
            return;

        int count = this.Count;

        // Step 1: Clear the old items
        this.Items.Clear();

        // Step 2: Add new items
        if (!collection.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            foreach (T item in collection)
            {
                this.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        // Step 3: Don't forget the event
        if (this.Count != count)
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is old but I just found it and cannot compile. It's missing any reference to IEnumerableUtils.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on previous answers yet, so I'm adding here a RemoveRange adaptation of the SmartCollection implementations above that won't throw a C# InvalidOperationException: Collection Was Modified. It uses a predicate to check if the item should be removed which, in my case, is more optimal than creating a subset of items that meet the remove criteria.

```
public void RemoveRange(Predicate<T> remove)
{
    // iterates backwards so can remove multiple items without invalidating indexes
    for (var i = Items.Count-1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (remove(Items[i]))
            Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
    this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
    this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

Example:

```
LogEntries.RemoveRange(i => closeFileIndexes.Contains(i.fileIndex));
```

Answer (score 2):

For the past few years I am using a more generic solution to eliminate too many ObservableCollection notifications by creating a batch change operation and notifying observers with a Reset action:

```
public class ExtendedObservableCollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ExtendedObservableCollection()
    {
    }

    public ExtendedObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base(items)
    {
    }

    public void Execute(Action<IList<T>> itemsAction)
    {
        itemsAction(Items);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Using it is straightforward:

```
var collection = new ExtendedObservableCollection<string>(new[]
{
    "Test",
    "Items",
    "Here"
});
collection.Execute(items => {
    items.RemoveAt(1);
    items.Insert(1, "Elements");
    items.Add("and there");
});
```

Calling Execute will generate a single notification but with a drawback - list will be updated in UI as a whole, not only modified elements. This makes it perfect for items.Clear() followed by items.AddRange(newItems).