# Are There any better way than using ObservableCollection for fast Binding in XAML?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, windows-phone, observablecollection

We are developing a Windows Phone application (CurrencyExchange) and there is a page that includes a textbox and a listbox. ListBox's itemsource is it's viewmodel's property type of observable collection. Textbox's textchange event is changing observable collection's all items but when observable changing and trying to bind listbox's items, the page is locking. I have seen a customobservable collection named Fastobservablecollection that is not running in viewmodel because it is using DispatcherObject and Dispatcherprioty that can't use in viewmodel. Are there any alternative that better than ObservableCollection?

```cs
List<Currency> newList = new List<Currency>(CurrencyConversions.ToList());
foreach (var item in newList)
{
    Double result;
    if (Double.TryParse(AmountPhone, NumberStyles.Any, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), out result))
        item.CalculatedValue = Math.Round(result * (Direction == "0" ? item.ConversionRateSell : item.ConversionRateBuy), 2);
    else
        item.CalculatedValue = 0;
}
CurrencyConversions = new ObservableCollection<Currency>(newList);
```

or

```cs
 List<Currency> newList = new List<Currency>();
 foreach (var item in CurrencyConversions)
 {
     Double result;
     if (Double.TryParse(AmountPhone, NumberStyles.Any, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), out result))
         item.CalculatedValue = Math.Round(result * (Direction == "0" ? item.ConversionRateSell : item.ConversionRateBuy), 2);
     else
         item.CalculatedValue = 0;
     newList.Add(item);
 }
 CurrencyConversions = new ObservableCollection<Currency>(newList);
```

Thanks.

With SmartCollection

```cs
List<Currency> newList = new List<Currency>(CurrencyConversions.ToList());
foreach (var item in newList)
{
    Double result;
    if (Double.TryParse(Amount, NumberStyles.Any, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), out result))
        item.CalculatedValue =Math.Round( result * (Direction == "0" ? item.ConversionRateSell : item.ConversionRateBuy),2);
    else
        item.CalculatedValue = 0;
 }
 CurrencyConversions = new SmartCollection<Currency>(newList);
```

Comment: Please add some code and how you update the Collection

Comment: You can also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302933/how-to-avoid-firing-observablecollection-collectionchanged-multiple-times-when-r) question if it provides useful information for you

Comment: I have added code and I am trying your advice now

Comment: I have tried it but no changes, still slow. Maybe I used it false. I have written last code in question, could you check it please?

Comment: How is the type `Currency` implemented?

Comment: Currency is our custom Class,

public Double ConversionRateBuy
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Double ConversionRateSell
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double _calculatedValue;
        public Double CalculatedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _calculatedValue;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty<double>(ref _calculatedValue, value, "CalculatedValue");
            }
        } ......

Answer (score 2):

You should not create a new `SmartCollection` each time, but more use only one instance and make modifications to the collection. I would suggest to change the implementation of your property `CurrencyConversions` to the following.

```
private SmartCollection<Currency> _conversions;
public SmartCollection<Currency> CurrencyConversions{
  get{
    if (_conversions == null) {
      _conversions = new SmartCollection<Currency>();
    }

    return _conversions;
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like so in your code:

```
CurrencyConversions.Reset(newList);
```

As I currently understand your code, you are not changing (adding and removing items) the collection, but rather change the property `CalculatedValue` of the type `Currency`. When the type `Currency` implements the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` there is no need to change the collection to update the UI, so changing your code to

```
foreach (var item in CurrencyConversions) {
  Double result;
  if (Double.TryParse(Amount, NumberStyles.Any, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), out result))
    item.CalculatedValue =Math.Round( result * (Direction == "0" ? item.ConversionRateSell : item.ConversionRateBuy),2);
  else
    item.CalculatedValue = 0;
  }
```

would be enough when your type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For that to work the property CalculatedValue should look like:

```
private double _value;
public double CalculatedValue{
  get{
    return _value;
  }
  set{
    _value = value;
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CalculatedValue"));
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It is giving me "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." error in foreach :)

Comment: I have changed foreach to for, but speed is the same as old.

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay i think there is something wrong in your code and that some revelant information is missing in your question. I do not observe an delay or performance issue using an ObservableCollection and UI updates.

Comment: Okey @Jehof, I will try to fix them, thanks for your interest.