# Is ObservableCollection<T> suitable in non UI scenarios

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I'm not very familiar with ObservableCollection but implementing it seems to provide me with a convenient way of updating a custom collections state based on any add/remove/replace/clear operation.

However, the examples I've looked at typically reference it in the context of WPF/WinForms data binding.

Does implementing it bring any unwanted overhead/dependencies that I should be wary of, ie. in my scenario (simply updating extended state which I have added to the collection based on adds/removes etc.) would it be better to just implement Collection or similar and update the extended state by overriding each add/remove/replace/clear operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason ObservableCollection is more often than not associated with UI is because of the flexibility it provides in updating the view if you are using MVVM pattern. Having said that I see no reason it should prevent you from using it in non-UI code. Please refer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007691/observablecollection-databinding-performance) for perfromance related information.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, interesting to see some performance data also. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no strong dependency with that collection if you want to use it outside of a WPF / WinForms application. It just implements a convenient interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tejs.. I was hoping this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the ObservableCollection has been introduced in the framework in version 3.0 which also introduced WPF, it has no strong link with UI concepts. Also if you read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), the description of the type does not refer to UI context in any way:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

The fact is that it is just well suited for UI scenarios as it already implements INotifiyPropertyChanged. So to reply your question, yes, it is totally ok using ObservableCollection in non-UI scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Ucodia..I've accepted Sandeeps answer as it contained some performance data to make the point. As you say the MSDN documentation led me to believe it was suitable but there are so many examples of it being used for UI when you search I wanted to make sure.